# How do I make a LinearLayout scrollable?

Tags: android

After I start the activity I am unable to scroll down to see other buttons and options in the xml defined below.

Does anyone know how to make this scrollable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#000044"
 android:isScrollContainer="true"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/title"
  android:text="@string/title"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editTitle"
  android:text=""
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/description"
  android:text="@string/description"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editDescription"
  android:text=""
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/location"
  android:text="@string/location"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
 <EditText
  android:id="@+id/editLocation"
  android:text=""
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/startTime"
  android:text="@string/startTime"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
 <DatePicker 
  android:id="@+id/DatePicker01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 <TimePicker 
  android:id="@+id/TimePicker01" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/endTime"
  android:text="@string/endTime"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
 <DatePicker 
  android:id="@+id/DatePicker02" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 <TimePicker 
  android:id="@+id/TimePicker02" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/buttonCreate"
  android:text="Create"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My class code is

```
package com.example.blah;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class example extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a LinearLayout scrollable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055537/how-do-you-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable)

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Place your layout in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: This is side effects, such as not being able to place scrollable elements inside a scrollview such as a listview.

Comment: You should avoid scrollable content inside scrollable content. Users wont like it (you never know which scroll you will move).

Comment: @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins if you aren't going to benefit from the adapter functionality of the ListView, then you can simply add all the elements of your list in a LinearLayout wrapper to make it feel all streamlined in the scrollable box along with other elements.

Comment: That will not make a good scrollable layout, aspecially if you have tabs and want to move between them. It will not move properly and it will show a bar on the side as well while you scroll

Answer (score 80):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView ...>

    <LinearLayout ...>

        ...
        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 67):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        Your views go here...

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 18):

Put your whole content in linear layout which is placed inside `ScrollView`.

`ScrollView` takes only one layout as its child.

```
isScrollContainer="true"
```

This property is used when your softkey in android pops up and still you want your view to scroll.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it using [View.scrollTo(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) also.

```
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                counter = (int) (counter + 10);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);

                    llParent.scrollTo(counter , 0);
                }

            }
        }, 1000L);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make any layout scrollable. Just under `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` add these lines:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and at the end add `</ScrollView>`

example of a non-scrollable activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    tools:context="p32929.demo.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After making it scrollable, it becomes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
        tools:context="p32929.demo.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a **LinearLayout** scrollable because it is not a scrollable container.

Only scrollable containers such as **ScrollView**, **HorizontalScrollView**, **ListView**, **GridView**, **ExpandableListView** can be made scrollable.

I suggest you place your LinearLayout inside a ScrollView which will by default show vertical scrollbars if there is enough content to scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView ...>

    <LinearLayout ...>

        ...
        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Note :** *ScrollView* takes only one view as its child. So better that child view be a *Linear Layout*

Answer (score 1):

Place all your layouts inside a ScrollView with width and height set to fill_parent.

Comment: Your reply looks like a comment rather than an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).  If you intended to give an answer, read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing a quality answer.

Comment: fill_parent already deprecated and replaced with match_parent

Answer (score 1):

try this below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.blah"
    >

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000044"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTitle"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editDescription"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:text="@string/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editLocation"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/startTime"
                android:text="@string/startTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/DatePicker01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/TimePicker01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/endTime"
                android:text="@string/endTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/DatePicker02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TimePicker
                android:id="@+id/TimePicker02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCreate"
                android:text="Create"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout></ScrollView></RelativeLayout>
```