# How do you make a LinearLayout scrollable?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have lot of items on the screen and I need to use the scrollbar so the user can scroll down. However, the scroll is either not visible or it's not working. How is it possible to add a scrollbar to a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a LinearLayout scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416689/how-to-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable)

Answer (score 491, accepted):

Wrap the linear layout with a `<ScrollView>`

[See here for an example:](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
                  <!-- Content here -->
            </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

> Note: **fill_parent** is deprecated and renamed to **match_parent** in API Level 8
>   and higher.

Comment: @DanielMagnusson Link still works here... here's a video guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNX996ZZ2CI

Comment: I don't think you need the outer LinearLayout.

Comment: @Lawrence No, it isn't necessary, but can depend on what the rest of your view looks like.

Comment: If you have only the Scrollview in the top linearlayout, you get the warning "This ScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view" which means to say it's pointless to have a linearlayout with only one item.

Comment: and some importatn notice: ScrollView must have only 1 child

Comment: @LawrenceKesteloot That's what i tought but if you're on api >= 28 ther's a syntax error because ScrollView tag just can render one child into in, so that's why you close into a LinearLayout tag to skip this thing.

Comment: @FernandoUrban I think you're referring to the inner `LinearLayout`. I was referring to the outer (top-level) one.

Comment: fill_parent (deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher)

Comment: Use androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView instead of Scroll View

Comment: Note: This only allows for vertical scrolling. To scroll horizontally, you must use a [HorizontalScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317648/making-a-linear-layout-horizontally-scrollable).

Answer (score 154):

```
<ScrollView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/scroll" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to wrap your linear layout with a scroll view

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I did it by trial and error.

```
ScrollView - (the outer wrapper).

    LinearLayout (child-1).

        LinearLayout (child-1a).

        LinearLayout (child-1b).
```

Since ScrollView can have only one child, that child is a linear layout.  Then all the other layout types occur in the first linear layout.  I haven't tried to include a relative layout yet, but they drive me nuts so I will wait until my sanity returns.

Comment: Could you fix the formatting please. Your first line has been missed from the code section and the site won't let me fix it as it is too trivial an edit.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using the tag `<ScrollView>`. For **ScrollView**, one thing you have to remind that, **ScrollView must have a single child**.

If you want your full layout to be scrollable then add `<ScrollView>` at the top. Check the example given below.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Content here -->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But if you want some part of your layout to be scrollable then add `<ScrollView>` within that part. Check the example given below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <!-- Content here -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the following attribute and enclose it within the linear layout

```
<LinearLayout ...>
<scrollView ...> 

</scrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <---------Content Here --------------->
            </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) as the first child of Layout file and now put your linearlayout inside it. Now, android will decide on the basis of content and device size available whether to show a scrollable or not.

Make sure linearlayout has no sibling because [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) can not have more than one child.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wanted to make a layout scrollable, you can use `<ScrollView>` With a layout or component in it.

Answer (score -29):

You can add an atrribute in linearLayout : `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

Comment: This controls the visibility of the scrollbars only. But it does not creates a scrollview for you.