# making a linear layout horizontally scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

How can I make a Linear layout horizontally scrollable? I just wrap a linear layout in myscrollview, I did what's needed in my XML file too but it still cannot scroll horizontally for contents which exceeds the linear layout size. Here is my XML:

```
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/popup"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="5dip"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:overScrollMode="always" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tracks"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dip"/>

    </ScrollView >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scroller"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check the answer i have edited..

Comment: HAve u seen the edited programmm u have to add the xml file and class check once....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this link http://android.okhelp.cz/horizontalscrollview-scrollview-horizontal-vertical-android-xml-example/

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;

  public class HorizontalscroolActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageButton btn11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);


    ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);


    ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);


}

  }
```

In XMLFILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic7"
                android:text="image1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:text="image2"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview2" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:text="image3"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic7" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview3" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton
                android:text="image4"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pic5" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Textview4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Now it scrolls but I cannot see the icon images which are in imageviews in linearlayout, I have in my linear layout.

Answer (score 7):

Please use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Answer (score 5):

Are tried with `<HorizontalScrollView ></HorizontalScrollView>` Tag?
Just try with above tag on the place of