# Is it possible to make a linear layout scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a vertical linear layout and placed many items in it, and **only part of them** can be displayed on the screen. I can see the first several items of the layout but can't see the last several items of the layout.
How can I make the linear layout **scrollable** so the user can scroll the screen to see the last several items of the linear layout?
 following is the content of the layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gridw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Grid Width"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_gridw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gridh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Height"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_gridh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gridbt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Border thickness"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_gridborderthickness"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_bgw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="BgImg Width"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_bgw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_bgh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Height"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_bgh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_mtgw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="MTG Width"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_mtgw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_mtgh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Height"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_mtgh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Margin(left, top, right, bottom):"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_margin_l"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_margin_t"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_margin_r"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_margin_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Background image file path name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_thumbdir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Thumbnail images directory path name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_thumbdir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_treasure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Treasure image file path name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_treasure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_signature"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Signature image file path name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_signature"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="reset"
            android:text="Reset" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_apply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="apply"
            android:text="Apply" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a LinearLayout scrollable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055537/how-do-you-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should wrap your `LinearLayout` in a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ScrollView`, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_gridw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Grid Width"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_gridw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_gridh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Height"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_gridh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_gridbt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Border thickness"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_gridborderthickness"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_bgw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="BgImg Width"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_bgw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_bgh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Height"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_bgh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_mtgw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="MTG Width"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_mtgw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_mtgh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Height"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_mtgh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Margin(left, top, right, bottom):"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_margin_l"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_margin_t"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_margin_r"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_margin_b"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Background image file path name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_thumbdir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Thumbnail images directory path name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_thumbdir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_treasure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Treasure image file path name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_treasure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_pathname_signature"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Signature image file path name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pathname_signature"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="Reset" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_apply"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="apply"
                android:text="Apply" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView works fine and my problem has been solved. Thank you all.

Comment: to  Jules Mazur, I tried, but failed to delete this question. It said "Sorry, this question has answers and can't be deleted..."