# How to set Multiple Listview with wrap_content in a single Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use one linearLayout and put 3 listview in that. I want to scroll whole the view which have 3 listview. when i do this with the fix height and width of every listview whole view is scroll smoothly. but when i make the height and width of listView as wrap_content that whole view is not scroll and i need the listview with wrap_content.

Please give the solution or suggestion for this.

Comment: go through the link u'll get answer of ur problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306679/how-to-make-linearlayout-scrollable-without-using-scrollview/8306910#8306910

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put any vertical scrolling View into another vertical scrolling View. The ListView has no absolute height, so it would not work correclty.

What you could do instead is to use a ScrollView that contains 3 LinearLayouts (instead of the ListViews).

Or use one ListView to present all your data i.e. from 3 different Cursors using  a [MergeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html).

There are many possibilities, so what kind of data do you present, and how do want it to look like?