# How can I make a RelativeLayout scrollable without using a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've got a RelativeLayout and I need to obtain a scrollable Layout without using a ScrollView, how can I do this?

Comment: According to [Official Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) I am afraid there's no attributes that will make a relative layout scrollable without using `ScrollView`, IMO they wouldn't have created a `ScrollView` or `ListView` in case they wanted to allow that. You could also take a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226931/make-linearlayout-scrollable-without-using-scrollview) that was asked here before.. Not sure if it would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ListView` or `RecycleView` and make your `RelativeLayout` as an item of `ListView` or `RecycleView`.  You can follow it - [Android 5.0 - Add header/footer to a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview)