# Android app does not allow me to scroll down

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Currently I am trying to build an app for Android.

My problem I am facing is that my app has a couple of buttons which fill my screen (using a Samsung Galaxy S3 to test the app) and I cannot scroll down to see the rest.

I would like to be able to scroll down for users who may have a smaller resolution.

Comment: You should post some code for the problem

Comment: What type of layout are you using?  As stated by @fvrghl, you need to post your layout.

Comment: Check out question: [how-to-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416689/how-to-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your layout in a

`<ScrollView>`

...

`</ScrollView>`