# Scrollview not working even after adding only one child to it

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I just wonder why my view is not scrollable. As told by the following links:

[How to make a LinearLayout scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416689/how-to-make-a-linearlayout-scrollable)

[Making LinearLayout Scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165387/making-linearlayout-scrollable)

I've got my linear layout within the scrollview and there is only one child for the scroll view. Still my view is not scrollable. Could someone tell me why it is not working.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.tdg.nottssports.FirstActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contact" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="hello world" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Telephone" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etTelephone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:text="07424063798" 
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address Line 1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etAddrLine1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="hello world"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView42"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address Line 2" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etAddrLine2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="hello world" 
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView43"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Town" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etTown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="hello world" 
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView44"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="PostCode" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPostCode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="hello world"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView144"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Visit" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDateVisit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMapView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Map View" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I accidentally missed the following portion in my question.

I've got the following code in Activity.java where I add images dynamically to the LinearLayout with the help of ImageView.

```
LinearLayout linearContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearContainer);

ImageView imageViews = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

linearContainer.addView(imageViews);

btnAddImage.setOnClickListener() {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    imageViews.addView(image);
    image.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

Does the above create any problem to scrolling? If yes, kindly help me out how to make it work.

Comment: layout structure seems to be proper. It will scroll only if screen height is not enough to fit the contents. Try adding few more views.

Comment: Hmm, works perfectly fine on my emulator device, I just needed to add a couple of more Buttons to be able to scroll down.

Comment: @miselking Could you please check it now. I've added the missing code now.

Comment: @AbhishekV Could you please check it now. I've added the missing code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this way:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Or an another way is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:onClick="editItem"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/button_edit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set fillViewPort property of scrollview to true.it should work then after.hope it will help.